# Who put that "Stack Overflow" thing in my VS 2013 caption?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Just recently, somehow I found this to be my upper right caption in Visual Studio .NET 2013:

[image]

I've got several Add-ins installed like:

- Visual Studio Commands (VSCommands)
- ReSharper
- VisualSVN

and carefully searched all their settings but found none that is responsible for putting that thing into the caption bar.

Most probably I'm just blind and oversaw an option. One way to get rid of it is to right-click the SO icon:

[image]

Just out of curiosity I really would love to know which Add-in (if any) put this text box into my Visual Studio.

**So my question is:**

How did the Stack Overflow search field appear in Visual Studio?

Comment: What's so bad about it being there?

Comment: @Malky.Kid it's not 'bad'. I was also curious where the SO search comes from in the IDE.

Comment: Consider replacing the title. The tone is a bit negative :)

Comment: I think that while the question is about IDE it's more suitable for SuperUser. However I'm in doubt here and want to listen to others.

Comment: @Malky.Kid ironically, stackoverflow is usually the last place I look to get answers.  Also it seems to be polling the SO site continually.  (As fiddler reported).

Comment: @bahrep: An IDE is a programming tool, so there is no reason this question can't stay here.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's [VSCommands 3.0](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece) (Visual Studio Commands extension). See their blog post which covers this new feature: [VSCommands 3.0.0](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/release-notes/3.0.2).

Answer (score 1):

It is a Feature of VSCommands, which is a handy tool, but honestly it is easy to get lost in all the options; I kinda wish i could find an add-in that was just the stack-overflow status(i am way too busy/lazy to make one.)